# Why Go generics not support Struct as return value?

Tags: go, generics

Go version is 1.18-rc, here is my code:

```
type Dog struct {
    Name    string
    CanBark bool
}

type Cat struct {
    Name     string
    CanClimb bool
}

type Pet interface {
    Dog | Cat
}

func GetDog[p Pet]() p {
    return Dog{
        Name:    "Sam",
        CanBark: true,
    }
}
```

when I run the code, I got the message "cannot use (Dog literal) (value of type Dog) as p value in return".

Comment: generics are useful to write **generic** code. If you need to use specific types in a function, you might have to resort to specialized code as type switches, assertions, etc.

Comment: something is not right here. Either Pet is empty interface, either Dog and Cat has a common method to build upon.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly return as "Dog", it want "p"

You should check the type so that will work.

This is the example

```golang
func GetDog[p Pet]() p {
    a := new(p)
    i := any(a)
    switch i.(type) {
    case *Dog:
        v := Dog{"Sam", true}
        return any(v).(p)
    default:
        v := Cat{"Caty", true}
        return any(v).(p)
    }
}
```

and finally this is the [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VErgnyN2K-H?v=gotip)

Comment: I think *Pet* interface is generics which include *Dog* and *Cat*, so I need not switch which type to return, generics is useless if I use switch case, do I understand correctly?

Comment: I think its not that useless, maybe this will replace golang users who generally use NewXxx. Who's know?

Comment: @RahmatFathoni I have a question related to ticker [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274938/use-ticker-to-periodically-load-all-the-files-in-memory-from-a-path-which-keeps). I was wondering if you can help me out with the design and how to handle it efficiently as I recently started with golang. I will appreciate any help.